# Як перекласти з англійської "greeter"?

Tags: переклад, from-english

Виникла проблема при перекладі слова *"greeter"*, яке має значення "людина, яка закликає відвідувачів зайти у заклад" або ж вона знаходиться в закладі, вітається з кожним хто туди заходить та може підтримувати коротку бесіду. Тобто це така професія.

І якщо у російській мові є варіант "зазывала", який більш-менш підходить для перекладу цього слова, то який варіант для українського перекладу? Гугл перекладач дає варіант "зазивала", але такого слова нема в СУМі.
У Вікіпедії мені вдалося знайти назву фільма переведеного як "Зазивало", однак і такого слова немає у СУМі.

Comment: Без джерел, так, що в голову прийшло: **_вітальник_**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Як Ви правильно відмітили переклад слова "greeter" з англійської мови на російську буде "зазывала" ([Англо-русский синонимический словарь](https://synonymum_en_ru.academic.ru/50656)).

[Російсько-український народний сучасний словник 2009–](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=all&highlight=on)  надає такий переклад:

> *Зазывала – **закли́кач, закликайло, закликачка, заклика́льник, закликальниця, зама́нювач, зама́нювачка, клику́н.***
> *Скрізь коло крамни́ць стоя́ть хло́пці-кликуни́ і зазива́ють ко́жен до своє́ї крамни́ці* (АС)

З СУМ-20

> **[Закликальник](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=135187&page=977)** Той, хто закликає кого-небудь кудись. *Перед стамбульською крамницею стояв закликальник* (із журн.).
>
> **[Закликальниця](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=135188&page=977)** Жін. до заклика́льник. *Продовжує агітувати закликальниця Ольга. – Думаєте, у часи Гоголя реклами менше було? Та
> вона вічна!* (з газ.).
>
> **[Заманювач](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=216477&page=998)** а, ч., розм. Той, хто заманює кого-небудь. *Вона сама собі на голову кликала всілякого штибу заманювачів та
> обманювачів, така вже її особливість* (Є. Гуцало); *У досвідчених
> заманювачів є своя власна психологічна сітка, якщо угледіли свого
> клієнта, якщо навчилися більш-менш правдиво грати віру в те, що
> говорять* (з газ.).
>
> **[Кликун](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=42161&page=1332)** а́, ч., заст. Той, хто прилюдно оголошував що-небудь; оповісник. *Управителі зганяли народ, послали кликунів по улицях, самі
> їздили, викликали, але ні одна жива душа не вийшла на майдан* (І.
> Нечуй-Левицький).

На мою думку, для Вашого випадку найбільш вдалими будуть слова ***"закликальник***" та ***"закликальниця"***, оскільки біля слова **"заманювач"** є позначка *розмовне*, а біля **"кликун"** - *застаріле*.

Answer (score 1):

[вітач](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D1%96%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) is the best option here, but you may add a word like 'вітач відвідувачів' to make it even more descriptive.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE!
Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/).

Comment: Добрий день, до попереднього коментаря додам, що посилання на російську вікі не дуже працює на цьому сайті, бо двома його робочими мовами є українська й англійська, отже велика частина користувачів може не розуміти російської.